# The usage of snprintf

Tags: c++, printf

Isn't it possible?
When I remove d[%s], it was okay.
Would you explain the reason?

```
std::string toString() const {
  char buf[1024];
  int a, b, c;
  std::string d;
  snprintf(buf, 1024, "a[%d] b[%d]" "c[%d] d[%s]", a, b, c, d);
  return buf;
}
```

Comment: `%s` awaits a null-terminated char arrays, not a `std::string`. Use `d.c_str()`.

Comment: [`snprintf` (and all related functions)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) are compatibility functions brought over from the C-heritage of C++. Therefore they can't handle C++ classes and objects.

Comment: there is a lot of things wrong with that function. first off returning stack space, second using C++, just use the standard library, `ostringstream`

Comment: @self Nothing is wrong here except the `d` - There is no "returning stack space" since the function returns a `std::string`, and ostream vs. snprintf is a pure matter of taste (I personally find this code much clearer than its stream equivalent).

Comment: he is returning a char array, named `buf` @Holt

Comment: @Holt *ostream vs. snprintf is a pure matter of taste* -- Until you get that bug, where your output exceeds the array size.  And yes, I have had to fix code that looks like the OP's for that one reason.

Comment: @self No - Read the code, this is equivalent to `return std::string(buf);`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Can't disagree with that, but it depends on your input. If you known the size beforehand, or if you can bound it simply, I would still go for `snprintf`. But this is not a "bug" here.

Comment: @Holt -- Depends on what one would consider a bug.  What if you need to see all of the information, but the buffer is too small?  Sure, you won't get a buffer overrun, but the returned string is truncated, which may not be acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

[`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) does not work with `std::string`. The `%s` modifier is specified as follow:

> The argument must be a pointer to the initial element of an array of characters. [...]

You need to pass a null-terminated array of characters. Fortunately, you can use [`c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) from `std::string` to obtain such pointer.

Just change your code to:

```
snprintf(buf, 1024, "a[%d] b[%d]" "c[%d] d[%s]", a, b, c, d.c_str());
```

Comment: Oh! Error was removed. Thanks!